# node.js express-coffee Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I installed the latest [express-coffee](https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee) and installed [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) too. I created a simple src/config/default.yaml

```
Database:
    db_host: localhost
    db_name: test
```

In my src/models/index.coffee

```
config = require('config').Database

console.log "host: #{config.db_host}"
```

But when trying to start the server with `cake dev` or even `cake build && node app` I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot write runtime.json file Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
```

Tried searching for the issue here and on Google but wasn't able to find anything. Even the few hits on just ENOENT or node-config runtime.json haven't been helpful. Anyone else run into this problem before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was where config/default.yaml was located. I had to move this to the root directory of the application. Moving it to the root - config/default.yaml fixed the issue.
The error message wasn't very helpful in figuring out what was going on.